# when i simulate the app on my device the buttons move

Tags: xcode, swift, button

When I simulate the app on my device the buttons move down from where I have them placed in the storyboard. I am using SWIFT. Ive had this before and all the sudden it disappeared one day  Any suggestions? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information pertaining to your issue. Your question is not only vague, but there's also no context provided. Look at the 'How to Ask a Question" Rules, Specifically:

**Be specific**

If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer.

**Make it relevant to others**

We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.